# Альтернатива scsi_logging_level в ранних ядрах Linux

Tags: linux, логирование, kernel, модули

Я сейчас работаю с ядром 2.4.32. И мне нужно включить отладочную печать для scsi.
Утилиты scsi_logging_level похоже, в ядре еще не было. Как я могу без этой утилиты посмотреть установленные уровни логирования, и если потребуется, задать свои?

Comment: Этой версии ядра лет 16? Некрофилия — не болезнь! (Если уж совсем никак, читайте исходники драйвера)

Comment: А что мне даст чтение драйвера? Ну увидел я строчку 
`SCSI_LOG_MLQUEUE(3, printk("Leaving scsi_do_cmd()\n"));` Узнал, что строчка будет выводиться если SCSI_LOG_MLQUEUE установлен в значение больше 3. Но я то спрашивал о том, как мне в окружении из консоли установить это значение.

Comment: Читайте ещё исходники. Не уверен, правда, что найденное вам понравится (нет, я не некрофил, версии ниже 2.6.12 нет никакого желания смотреть)

Comment: Я это нашел. Вдруг, кому-то понадобится(не дай Бог).

Usage: echo "scsi log token #N" > /proc/scsi/scsi where token is one of [error,scan,mlqueue,mlcomplete,llqueue,llcomplete,hlqueue,hlcomplete]